# storing info onto a form page on the next page

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, session-storage

Trying to work out how how i can store information from one web page into a form on an apply page.
basically the first page has 2 jobs that a user can apply for, both with a unique 5 digit job reference number specific to that job.

the user is able to click on that  code which jumps to the same application page however that specific job number is saved within the form above.

i understand javascript is needed but not sure on how to use it.
a hand with steps would be great.

i have some example code bellow..

Jobs page

```
  <ul>
        <li><strong>Job Reference Number: </strong>wru01</li>
        <li><strong> Position Title:</strong> CSS Website Designer</li>
        <li><strong> Salary range:</strong> $50-60k gross per year</li>
        <li><strong>Job Description:</strong> working and intergrating 
    with the HTML and Javascript team as well as with our clients in 
    designing 
    their asthetics of their website. The position will also entaile 
     research 
    into new CSS updates that can give WRU a competitive edge over 
     others</li>
        <li><strong>Head of CSS (report to):</strong> John Striger </li>
        <li><strong> Key responsibilities:</strong>
            <ol>
        <li>future research and updates of CSS</li>
        <li>working 1 on 1 with clients</li>
        <li>working with Html and Javascript teams to reach our company 
      goals</li>
        <li>Creating CSS for customers and designing their website</li>
            </ol>
        </li>
        <li><strong> Required Skills:</strong>
            <ol>
                <li> have passed Website development at uni</li>
                <li> have a portfolio of at least 5 CSS website 
    designs</li>
                <li> have over 2 years experience of working at a web 
    company</li>
                <li> Amazing people skills</li>
            </ol>
```

APPLICATION PAGE

```
  <form id=form action=https://mercury.swin.edu.au/it000000/formtest.php 
  method="post">

<fieldset style=width:50%>
    <legend> Personal Information:</legend>
    <label> First Name:
    <input type="text" name="firstname" pattern="^[a-zA-Z ]+$" 
 required="required" maxlength="20"/></label> 
    <br/><br/>
    <label> Last Name:
    <input type="text" name="lastname" pattern="^[a-zA-Z ]+$" 
 required="required" maxlength="20"/>
    </label> 
    <br/><br/>
    <label>Date of birth:  <input type="text" name="birth date" 
 placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" maxlength="10" pattern="\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}" 
 required="required"/></label>
    <br/><br/>
</fieldset>
<fieldset style=width:50%>
    <legend> Gender:</legend> 
    <label>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male" checked="checked" 
 />Male</label>    
    <label>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female"  />Female</label>
     <br/><br/>
</fieldset>
<fieldset style=width:50%>
    <legend>Address</legend>
    <label> Street Address:
    <input type="text" name="address" required="required" maxlength="40"/> 
 </label> 
    <br /><br />
    <label> Suburb/Town:
    <input type="text" name="suburb" required="required" maxlength="40"
    pattern="^[a-zA-Z ]+$"></label> 
    <br/><br/>
    <label> Postcode:
    <input type="text" name="postcode" required="required" pattern="[0-9] 
 {4}"/></label> 
    <br/><br/>
    <label> State:
    <select name="rank" id="state">
    <option disabled selected value >Please Select Your State</option>

    <option value="Vic" >Vic</option>

    <option value="NSW" >NSW</option>

    <option value="QLD" >QLD</option>

    <option value="NT" >NT</option>

    <option value="WA" >WA</option>

    <option value="SA" >SA</option>

    <option value="TAS">TAS</option>

    <option value="ACT">ACT</option>   
    </select>  
    </label>
    <br /> <br />
    <label> Email Address
    <input type="email"
    placeholder="Enter your email">
    </label>
    <br /><br />
    <label> Phone Number:
    <input type="text" name="phonenumber" required="required"
    pattern="[0-9 ]{8,12}"/></label>        
   </fieldset>

  <fieldset style=width:50%>
 <legend>Job Application Information: </legend>
  <label> Job Reference Number:
    <input type="text" name="refnumber" required="required" pattern="[a- 
 zA-Z0-9]{5}"/></label>
 <br /><br />
 <label>Skill set:</label>
 <br />
 <label><input type="checkbox" name="skill[]" value="CSS" 
 checked="checked"/>CSS</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="skill[]" value="HTML" 
 />HTML</label> 
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="skill[]" value="JavaScript" 
 />JavaScript</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="skill[]" value="management" 
 />management experience</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="skill[]" value="PHP" 
 />PHP</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="skill[]" value="other" />other 
 skills (please list bellow)</label>
      <br/><br/>
      <label>Other Skills:</label>
      <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="otherskills" placeholder="Enter 
 any other skills that would be usefull for the job..."></textarea>

  </fieldset>
<p>
    <button type="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
    <button type="reset" value="submit">Reset</button>
    </p>

 </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below

Job page: Add a link anchor tag on job reference number

```
<li><a href="link to form page?refnumber=wru01"><strong>Job Reference Number: </strong>wru01</a></li>
```

Form page: HTML

```
<input id="refnumber" type="text" name="refnumber" required="required" />
```

Form page: Add Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload=function(){
    var url_string = window.location.href;
    var url = new URL(url_string);
    var c = url.searchParams.get("refnumber");
    document.getElementById("refnumber").value=c;
  }    
</script>
```